# Technology behind cinemagraph

Tags: animation, image-processing, gif, mp4, animated-gif

I want to understand the technology behind cinemagraph.
Is there any open source project out there which helps in creating cinemagraphs from MP4 files?

Is there any standard specification to create cinemagraph file format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cinemagraphs are nothing but a fancy name for short videos or animations that usually show a seamless motion which makes them more appealing to the viewer.

Not the format makes them what they are, its the content that matters...

You can save them in any format you want. Of course it would make sense to use a format that can be played by your targeted software. Hence if oyu want to display them in a webbrowser animated gifs would be a reasonable choice.

Comment: When we see cinemagraph image on web, is it GIF always?
Or is it like if we want to save cinemagraph image, we would have to save it in form of gif or mp4 or something else?

Comment: @ManishGautam of course it is not always gif. you can do this in many ways but I guess gif is the most common. there are also embedded videoplayers and whatnot... imagine you want to record a video. you can put it on an sd-card or a magnet tape or whatever you like. but if you want to play it on a dvd player it would make sense to have it on a dvd. same goes for file formats. use a format that suits your needs.